# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función que cambie automáticamente su argumento en R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo esta función que me entrega gráficos de mis datos, pero necesito que me entregue mas de 100 gráficos diferentes al cambiar el valor de ***habilliage***. Usando "ploteando" me entrega los gráficos correspondientes al valor de entrada pero no encuentro la forma de que el argumento se actualice solo y me genere todos los gráficos de una vez, no se si se puede.

```
ploteando <- function(k){
ploter <- 1
for (i in 1:k){
  if(i > 0){ploter = (i+k)}
  return(fviz_mca_ind(mca.chunk, 
                      label = "none", 
                      habillage = ploter, 
                      palette = c("#FF0000", "#8B0000", "#0000FF", "#FF1493", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#808080", "#800000", "#4B0082"),
                      addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.type = "confidence",
                      ggtheme = theme_minimal()))
}}
```

Si alguien sabe como solucionar eso se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

va un ejemplo completo que funciona:

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

res.mca <- MCA(tea[1:18]) #Un MCA muy simple con los datos ejemplo. 


ploteando <- function(modelo) # Es mejor no parametrizar el nombre de un objeto y que sea argumento de la función y no parte del código. 
  {
  for (i in 1:length(names(modelo[["call"]][["X"]]))) { #Extraigo del modelo la cantidad de variables para pasar a habbillage
  grafico <- fviz_mca_ind(modelo, 
               habillage = i,   #Simplemente itero cada variable por número de índice
               palette = c("#FF0000", "#8B0000", "#0000FF", "#FF1493", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#808080", "#800000", "#4B0082"))
  print(grafico)}
  }

ploteando (res.mca)
```

Genera los 18 gráficos, pintado cada uno por la variable que tiene ese número de índice. No debería tener problema para agregar las elipses y otros argumentos que están en tu pregunta.

Comment: Genera perfeto los graficos, el unico problema es con algunos en particular que al añadir las elipses da este error "Computation failed in `stat_conf_ellipse()`:
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: ¿El problema es con tu datos o los del ejemplo que pongo? Si es con tus datos no creo que pueda ayudarte si no incluyes al menos un ejemplo que permita reproducir el error. Sin esa información todo lo que podría decirte es lo obvio: que se coló un `NA` donde no debería estar, pero no sé donde, como ni porque. Podrías revisar como estás manejando los missing en tus datos, quizás vengan desde ahí.